# mysql multi query function is incorrect

Tags: php, mysql

As I read the php manual on this function, I though that I was executing it correctly.
Unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given on line 94
```

with this code:

```
$upSQL = "SELECT * FROM rated_teams WHERE server='$server' AND name='$teamname' AND master='2' ORDER BY id ASC;";
$upSQL .="SELECT name, rating FROM rated_teams WHERE server='$server' AND master='1'";
//echo $upSQL. "<br />";
$upresult=mysqli_multi_query($con, $upSQL);
$i=1;
$j=1;
$myrating=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($upresult)) { //LINE 94
    if ($row['win'] == 1 && $i <= 3) {      
            echo $i++ . "first 3 wins <br />";
            $myrating+=10;
            $j++;

        } else {
            if ($row['name'] == $opposer && $row['master'] == 1) {
                echo $opposer . " " . $row['rating'];
                echo $j++. " j<br />";
            }

            }
}
echo $myrating;
```

So, the direct question is: Why is this code incorrect?

Comment: The error message tells you that the query did not run properly.  You need to output the mysql error `mysql_error()` to see why it did not run.

Comment: You forgot the `;` at the end of the query.

Comment: Multiple query statements need to be delimited by `;` _in the SQL string_, in addition to the PHP statement `;` terminator.

Comment: Also to read the result of both queries it is slight different see here [**`mysqli_multi_query`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) for an example.

Comment: yes I added the ; at the end of first $upSQL and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Prix Yes, as I mentioned I was using that resource for my information on using that function. If you look at my coding, you'll notice that it's the "Procedural Style" and not the "Object-oriented Style"

Comment: @user2544291 no you're not, other you would have the mysqli_next being called and would not use the fetch_array on the entire result but localized that's why I pointed u to the docs which does list how to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysqli_multi_query` method returns a boolean, while the method `mysqli_fetch_array` is supposed to be passed a `mysqli_result`, as the error tells you. You need to instead use the `mysqli_store_result` method as seen here:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Using this method, you can loop through the results, as so:

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $upSQL)) {
do {
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            $currentresult = $row[0];
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
} while (mysqli_next_result($con));
}
```

The do-while makes sure that your first result is there before going to the others, and gets that result, and then gives you the next results in the while segment of the loop. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to help. It would be wonderful if you could mark the answer as correct then.